# Por que tem função que precisa do return e outra não precisa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
    interface user {
    nome: string
}

function saudarComOla(pessoa: user) {
    console.log("Ola " + pessoa.nome)
}

function mudarNome(pessoa: user) {
    return pessoa.nome = "Vane"
}

const pessoa: any = {
    nome: 'João',
    idade: 25
}

saudarComOla(pessoa)
console.log(mudarNome(pessoa))
```

Por que na função `saudarComOla()` eu não preciso usar o `return` e na função `mudarNome()` eu preciso?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O comando `return` de uma linguagem tem duas funções: é um controle de fluxo e um indicativo que determina qual resultado deve ser entregue para quem chamou a função.

E antes de mais nada é preciso entender que uma função matemática sempre deve resultar em algo, ter um valor que deve ser usado depois que a função é avaliada. Se uma rotina é avaliada mas resulta em nada na verdade ela é um procedimento e não uma função, o que não é comum em matemática. Porém em programação às vezes é melhor modificar um pouco o comportamento matemático para facilitar o uso.

O primeiro caso é um procedimento e não uma função, e é o motivo dele resultar nada. Apesar disso, como todo o resto é igual a uma função a linguagem preferiu manter o nome de função (veja mais no final). Se a ideia é apenas executar algo e não resultar em algo por que retornaria algo?

Bem, ainda poderia usar o `return` como controle de fluxo, ou seja, usar o comando para sair da função (procedimento) antes do fim do algoritmo. Isso só faz sentido em casos condicionais. Se usasse o `return` fora de uma condição todo o resto do código não seria mais executado. E pra que colocar o `return` como último comando? Se o fim da função já sai dela de qualquer forma, o comando é inútil. O comando deve ser usado só para dizer **quando** o fluxo da rotina deve encerrar.

Então por ser o último comando do fluxo da função e não resultar em algo que precisa ser entregue para quem chamou, não tem porque usar o `return`. Poderia colocar o `return` lá no fim para ser mais explícito, mas na minha opinião só poluiria o código.

No segundo caso é uma função clássica, então mesmo que seja o último comando, ainda precisa indicar **o que** deve retornar para a chamadora, e a linguagem decidiu que deveria ser explícito quanto a isto (algumas permitem não usar o `return` ou fazer ele ser implícito).

Em JavaScript o que determina se é uma função ou não é apenas a presença de um valor válido em um `return`. Mas de certa forma podemos interpretar que tudo é função, porque um valor indefinido é sempre resultado em toda chamada de função, por esse critério, não existe procedimento mesmo, só função. E aí a linguagem definiu que na falta de um retorno explícito, o valor resultado seria indefinido. JS quer executar, não ser o mais legível, ele tenta fazer algo, mesmo que não seja o mais adequado.

Não nessa situação, mas o `return` é justamente um dos causadores de problemas por não usar `;`, então por que não usar o que a linguagem manda fazer? Ainda mais em TypeScript que é uma linguagem melhor que JS, mas que aceitou manter esse erro de aceitar ficar sem em algumas situações por questões e compatibilidade. Quem usa TS quer qualidade, e não vai ficar querendo economizar digitação. Em JS as pessoas em geral aceitam baixa qualidade e é mais comum, mas ainda é um erro, que funciona na maioria das situações.

Comment: Valew cara, ajudou e muito... ficou bem esclarecido, obrigado

Comment: Se resolveu você pode marcar a resposta com correta, veja o sinal verdinho ali do lado da resposta logo abaixo do placar. Depois se tiver mais votos pode votar também.